# How to do SQL queries using CachedRowSet?

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I'm trying to write a method using *CachedRowSet* for doing SQl queries. The sample code is as following ( the user and password is defined earlier ),

```
public CachedRowSet getContentsOfCoffeesTable( Connection connection ) throws SQLException {

    CachedRowSet crs = null;

    try {

        crs = new CachedRowSetImpl();

        crs.setType(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE);
        crs.setConcurrency(ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE);
        crs.setUsername(user);
        crs.setPassword(password);


        crs.setCommand("select COF_NAME, SUP_ID, PRICE, SALES, TOTAL from COFFEES");
        crs.execute();


    } catch (SQLException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return crs;
}
```

When I'm trying to read the data using the sample code, I get nothing.

```
CachedRowSet myValues =  getContentsOfCoffeesTable( myConn );
while( myValues != null && myValues.next() ){

     // get the values of 2nd column of the table 
     System.out.println( myValues.getString(2) );
}
```

COFFEES table is already populated. How can I improve the code ? Thanks.

Comment: If you managed to solve your problem, then you should not edit your question to add the solution, but instead you should post an answer with the solution. That is a lot more clear to other people, and will also allow you to accept your own answer.

Comment: Note that the original cause of your problem is that you haven't provided a connection to the cached row set (either to the row set itself, or to the execute method), so it simply can't query information as it doesn't have a connection.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I will care about this in future.

Comment: I suggest you do it for this question as well.

Comment: Okay, I post the answer. Thanks for showing me the right way of doing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find the solution of how to use CachedRowSet for doing SQL queries and changed the method as following,

```
public CachedRowSet getContentsOfCoffeesTable(Connection mycConn)
    throws SQLException {

CachedRowSet crs = null;
ResultSet resultSet = null;
Statement stmt = null;
String sql = "select COF_NAME, SUP_ID, PRICE, SALES, TOTAL from COFFEES";

try {

    stmt = myConn.createStatement();
    resultSet = stmt.executeQuery(sql);

    crs = new CachedRowSetImpl();
    crs.populate(resultSet);

}

catch (Exception e) {

    e.printStackTrace();
}

return crs;
 }
```

Then, it's possible to print the values s following,

```
// I get the Connection myConn here 
//  then pass the connection info to the method and get myValues 
// prit myValues for column index of 2 

CachedRowSet myValues =  getContentsOfCoffeesTable( myConn );
while( myValues != null && myValues.next() ){

     // get the values of 2nd column of the table 
     System.out.println( myValues.getString(2) );
}
```

Comment: You need to make it clear what exactly you changed to make it work. Not just a code dump.

Answer (score 0):

I find another way of doing this. In the initial post *url* information was not provided as follow,

```
cr.setUrl(url);
```

Where the value of the *url*,

```
url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/myDemo"
```

The method goes as following,

```
private CachedRowSet getContentsOfCoffeesTable(Connection con)
        throws SQLException {

    CachedRowSet cr = null;

    try {

        cr = new CachedRowSetImpl();
        cr.setType(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE);
        cr.setConcurrency(ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE);
        cr.setUsername(username);
        cr.setPassword(password);
        cr.setUrl(url);

        cr.setCommand("select COF_NAME, SUP_ID, PRICE, SALES, TOTAL from COFFEES");
        cr.execute();

    }

    catch (Exception ex) {

        ex.printStackTrace();
    }

    return cr;
}
```